# How to reproduce the distribution of p-values in a Monte Carlo?

Tags: distributions, p-value, simulation, monte-carlo

In whichever program (R preferred, but pseudo-code would do), could I get an idea of how Nassim Taleb simulated the distribution of p-values - I guess under the alternative hypothesis - on [this MOOC](https://youtu.be/ncqcFNHmMoc?t=350)?

Somehow he has to draw from two identical distributions that are offset in mean and or variance, in such a way that the alternative hypothesis is true, but he also knows the "true p-value" as $11$ in his simulation, and I wonder if this is the mean that he got after a random simulation of two Gaussians with different means, or whether he started with this $p<0.11$ value to retrofit the parameters of his distributions.

---

Without prefixing a p-value as a desired mean, it is quite easy:

```
n <- 10000
sam <- 1000
p.vals <- vector(,n)
for(i in 1:n){
u <- rnorm(sam,0.1,1)
v <- rnorm(sam,0,1)
p.vals[i] <- t.test(u,v)$p.value
}
hist(p.vals, border=F)
abline(v=mean(p.vals))
legend(mean(p.vals),3000,paste('Mean of p-values is', round(mean(p.vals),2)))
```

[image]

Comment: For some cases such as t tests and chi-s1uared tests, there are formulas using exact distribution theory (non-central t or chi-squared) that make simulation unnecessary. For some nonparametric tests where the distribution theory is not so simple, one can guess at sample size $n$ for a given P-value knowing $n$ for a roughly analogous parametric test. As you have shown, with simulation it is easier to simulate P-values for given sample sizes and effect sizes. // Your question is a bit open ended, please be more specific about which tests you have in mind and what quantity you want to simulate.

Comment: There is a [short paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07532.pdf) that elaborates on Taleb's claim about considering the p value of a test to be a random variable with a fat tail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a comment really - There are some parts of Taleb's lecture that either I don't understand or I don't agree with.

Taleb simulates the same experiment several times and he averages the p-values. In his setup the simulation is such that the average of the p-values is 0.11. His point is that because most of the p-values are well below the average, the p-value is a deceiving statistic. This is shown nicely in your histogram.

My objection is that averaging p-values doesn't make sense. I can't tell why formally but I don't think probabilities is something you can average straightaway. Instead I would take the mean of the log-transformed pvalues:

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 10000
sam <- 1000
p.vals <- vector(,n)
for(i in 1:n){
    u <- rnorm(sam,0.1,1)
    v <- rnorm(sam,0,1)
    p.vals[i] <- t.test(u,v)$p.value
}
logp <- -log(p.vals)
hist(logp, border= 'white', col= 'grey60', xlab= sprintf('-log(p-value)'), main= '')
abline(v=mean(logp))

mean(p.vals)
[1] 0.1085658

exp(-mean(logp))
[1] 0.0167
```

[image]

The anti-log of this mean in this case is ~0.017, much smaller than 0.11. In my opinion, 0.017 is closer to "gut feeling" since you are simulating samples of 2000 data points, quite large to detect a difference of 0.1 with sd= 1.

Other loosely related objections I have: Taleb says that p-values are stochastic - I see that since they are computed from random samples. However, the fact that a metric is stochastic doesn't mean that it is necessarily biased, which I think is what he let the audience understand. Also, the fact that p-values are abused and misunderstood (I agree), doesn't make p-values wrong or deceiving. Testing the same hypothesis multiple times will give small a pvalue in the long run and this is how p-values work, I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I didn't average the p values, I got one p value per experiment. I like your last paragraph. What is the point in log transforming the p values?

Comment: @Mathtourist *I didn't average the p values, I got one p value per experiment.* sure, but you average the resulting vector of pvalues when you do `mean(p.vals)` and you get ~0.11 as required. About log-transforming, I *think* you need it because you should multiply probabilities (or sum their logs), you can't sum probabilities. See also [Fisher's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method#:~:text=Under%20Fisher%27s%20method%2C%20two%20small,p-value%20is%20around%200.05.)

Comment: "you can't sum probabilities" as you would do to get the mean, correct?

Comment: Thank you! If you have a chance, please address my last comment.

Comment: @Mathtourist - yes, for the arithmetic mean you would need to sum probabilities and this is inappropriate.

Comment: New students sometimes make the mistake of adding probabilities of events to get the probability of the union of those events. Such a calculation requires the inclusion-exclusion principle to get the desired probability, which may lead to an intuition that probabilities cannot be added in general. However, I don't see a measure theory or sampling reason why unbiased estimates of the probability of a given event cannot be averaged.

Comment: The average log probability mentioned above can be rearranged into the geometric mean of the probabilities, however the logarithmic expression tends to have better floating point error.

Comment: I should clarify my wording in regards to the use of the inclusion-exclusion principle. It is a sum. What I meant is that students sometimes believe $P(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)$, rather than additionally subtracting and adding the appropriate intersections.

Comment: To correct myself on the point about geometric means, it is the antilog of the average of the log probabilities that can be rearranged into the geometric mean.

Comment: @Galen Thanks for comments. I struggle to interpret `mean(p.values)`. Ok, that is the expected value in a mathematical sense. However, it's not the *typical* value that you would observe from experiments as per OP's setup and I don't see it as a problem. In fact, with N=2000, true difference 0.1 and sd=1, it seems fine to me to observe p << 0.11 most of the time. Taleb shows that occasionally you do get large pvalues but that is how p-values work and it's fine by me! To me, it seems more an example showing when the mean *is not* a good statistic to report.

Comment: The [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) is a typical value in a '*[center of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass)*' sense, however perhaps you're more interested in the [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) which is the [maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) value.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[\rho]$ is a [population parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_parameter) that would provide a more conservative benchmark for avoiding [Type I errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors). Taleb believes that the mean should be paired to the theoretical $\rho$-value calculated from the theoretical distribution, which implies that we underestimate the true parameter from his perspective.

Comment: If the theoretical $\rho$ value for the given means, standard deviations, and sample sizes is 0.11, then we're not supposed to conclude a significant difference at the confidence limit $\alpha=0.05$. Taleb wants hypothesis testing in practice to reflect this fact.